# How to set different margins and limits for connected ranges

Tags: javascript, nouislider

I'm using [NoUiSlider](https://github.com/leongersen/noUiSlider) and my main use case is to have multiple ranges that can act independently.

For example, 2 ranges representing 2 yearly ranges:

- one range of 2002 (Start of 2002 to end of 2002)
- one range of start of 2007 to end of 2010.

Also, both ranges can be moved on the axis to change the years covered and the range size can be changed to include more or less years as well.

[image: Range Sliders]
This works fine.

However, I do have some constraints.  For example, the user can't create a range that is larger or smaller than a certain size.  NoUiSlider does have options that control this: [Margin](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-options/#section-margin) and [Limit](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-options/#section-limit).  These do enforce the restrictions but they act globally for all handles (in all ranges).

I really only care about enforcing the rules among **connected** handles in a single range.

In this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hbL4v0ce/ you can see the behavior.

```
var slider = document.getElementById('slider');

noUiSlider.create(slider, {
  start: [2002, 2003, 2008, 2012],
  step: 1,
  connect: [false, true, false, true, false],
  margin: 0,
  limit: 4,
  behaviour: 'drag',
  range: {
    'min': 2000,
    'max': 2016
  },
  pips: {
    mode: 'steps',
    density: -1
  },
});
```

The right range can't be moved any more to the right because one of the handles is already at the configured 4 unit limit away from the left range and similarly the left range can't be moved any more to the left.  This is not the behavior that I want.

If I could specify separate limits/margins for each connected range I think that would solve my problem.  Is it possible to do this?  Or is there another approach that would achieve my goals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

noUiSlider doesn't have a feature to use different margins/limits for different handles. You have multiple options:

- Abstract the years away from the slider, and map the slider values to years in a formatter. For example, you could have your slider run from 0 - 100, then map the values for the last two handles to 2007 - 2010. You could then enforce any constraints you have in the [`update` event](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/events-callbacks/#section-update). This might look/work better if you disable the `step` option, and implement ["soft limits"](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/examples/#section-soft-limits) instead.
- Alternatively, you could disable the `margin` option, and implement your margin behavior yourself using the `set` method in the `update` event. There's a pretty good example of how to do this in [this Github issue](https://github.com/leongersen/noUiSlider/issues/957#issuecomment-472937764).

Comment: I disabled margin and implemented the custom margin behavior using the set method in the update event which works. The **one** drawback of that approach vs. the native margin implementation is that the user is able to move the handle to an invalid position before the update/set moves it back to a valid position. I don't really love the ux of this and it may be confusing to a user.

Comment: What if margin (and limit) could accept a number **or** a function? If a function is passed in then margin would be set to 0 for calculation purposes and the function would be used to determine if the move is allowed and return false if the handle can't move. This way three is no need to reset the position since the move never happened.  Thoughts?

Comment: That'd be a possible improvement. You could file it on the project issue tracker!